# Angular 2 Typescript - Can't resolve all parameters for TooltipService

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, typescript, angular

I have this code which is injecting a service, which makes a http.get request,  into a component.

The component renders fine but I got an error once I injected the service into the component.

And get the error;

EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters for TooltipService: (?).

I've included the bootstrap since I believe its a DI issue,

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TooltipService } from '../../services/tooltip/tooltip.service';

@Component({
    ..,
    ..,
    providers: [TooltipService]
})

export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() explaination: boolean;
    @Input() nodeId: number;
    @Input() questionId: number;

    constructor(public tooltipService: TooltipComponent) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        if(this.explaination) {
            this.tooltipService.getExplaination(this.nodeId, this.questionId)
                .then(response => console.log(response));
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()

export class TooltipService {
    constructor(public http: HTTP) {}

    getExplaination(private nodeId: number, private questionId: number) {

        let url = `someUrl/`
                    + questionId + `/` + nodeId;

        return this.http.get(url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

}
```

-

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import {AppComponent} from '../app/components/app/app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        disableDeprecatedForms(),
        provideForms()
    ])
    .catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 typos in your code.

It's `Http`, not `HTTP`:

```
export class TooltipService {
    constructor(public http: Http) {}
```

You probably want to inject the service, not the component:

```
export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() explaination: boolean;
    @Input() nodeId: number;
    @Input() questionId: number;

    constructor(public tooltipService: TooltipService) {}
```

Comment: Happens to the best! :)